# How to avoid losing macros in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, vba, ms-office, phpexcel, excel-2007

I'm using PHPExcel to read data from a database and put it into a spreadsheet. I also have a template (.xlsm file) to be followed. As everybody knows, PHPExcel doesn't support macros. But I don't want to edit or create the macros. I just wanna make sure they remain where they are. Don't even want to touch them.

So, does anybody know any **workaround** for that?

I've been working on this for a week now. I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877704/is-there-a-php-library-for-xlsmexcel-with-macro-parsing-editing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913818/phpexcel-clone-xlsm-with-macros). The problem with the first solution is that my server is a Debian so I can't try Libxl approch.

In codeplex I've found the following [solution](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/208399) on Chads2000's comment, but I aint seem to be able to make it work. I'm desperate.

Thanks all for your attention, in antecipation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I figured this out quite a long time ago: [here's](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/19017) the answer. A guy made a workaround. First, he separate the macros files (VBA) from the sheet, then he left the PHPExcel "doing his thing", e then put it back (the macros!). It was enough for me! :D

Comment: above link is broken. they change site into ajax based issue loader. So, you need to go this link https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=phpexcel and search for "Excel 2007 - Macros - CustomUI"