# PHPexcel can not write column

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xlsm, vba

I am editing `.xlsm` file. Which has `macro` and multiple tabs.

**EDIT**

I tried with macro enable `.xlsx` file but same issues.

[image]

I always get below error when save file after editing.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message
>   'Invalid cell coordinate 'I|Gen'' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\work\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:594 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\work\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php(651):
>   PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString(''I|Gen'') #1
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\work\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php(624):
>   PHPExcel_Cell::absoluteCoordinate(''I|Gen'') #2
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\work\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Workbook.php(323):
>   PHPExcel_Cell::absoluteReference(''I|Gen'') #3
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\work\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Workbook.php(300):
>   PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Workbook->writeDefinedNameForNamedRange(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter),
>   Object(PHPExcel_NamedRange)) #4
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\work\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Workbook.php(269):
>   PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Workbook->writeNamedRanges(Object(PHPExcel_Shared_XMLWriter),
>   Object(PHPExcel)) #5
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\work\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Workbo
>   in D:\xampp\htdocs\work\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line
>   594

Below is my code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcelR = $objReader->load("20170407Simpledevelopmentv0.2.xlsm");

$objPHPExcelR->setActiveSheetIndex(11);
$worksheet = $objPHPExcelR->getActiveSheet();

$worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow('4','28','22,000');
//echo "kapil". $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow('4','28')->getValue(); die;
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcelR;

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
//$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);
$objWriter->save('20170407Simpledevelopmentv0.2.xlsm');

exit;
```

I get error when save the file. If I remove comment   `echo "kapil". $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow('4','28')->getValue(); die;` then it show data. I tried with the `$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);` but same issue.

Comment: Have you tried `$worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4,28, 22.000);`

Comment: no, let me try it

Comment: @RomanS : same error.

Comment: I think that it could be some macro-related issue if you have used some in your excel file. Could you try the same file with macros removed?

Comment: It's working without macros.

Comment: So just remove macros :) Or check this answer - it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809652/how-to-avoid-losing-macros-in-phpexcel

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can not remove macros and I have checked that answer it not working.